# tensorflow build in visual studio

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2015, tensorflow

i want build tensorflow with visual studio 2015. i download `cmake 3.9` and `git 2.14` and `swig 3.0.12` and make tensorflow solution with cmake.
then when build tensorflow solution, visual studio try to download external dependencies like `giflib`, `libpng` ,... but cant download `eigen` : `"f3a22f35b044.tar.gz"`
file, i download `'eigen-eigen-f3a22f35b044.tar.gz'` file manually and rename to `f3a22f35b044.tar.gz` and put in download directory but when i try again to build, VS again try to doawnlod file, VS output :

```
>  Performing download step (download, verify and extract) for 'eigen'
1>  -- File already exists but no hash specified (use URL_HASH):
1>    file='D:/Artificial Intelligence/Deep Learning/Src/tensorflow/tensorflow-master/Build2/downloads/f3a22f35b044.tar.gz'
1>  Old file will be removed and new file downloaded from URL.
1>  -- Downloading...
1>     dst='D:/Artificial Intelligence/Deep Learning/Src/tensorflow/tensorflow-master/Build2/downloads/f3a22f35b044.tar.gz'
1>     timeout='none'
1>  -- Using src='https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/get/f3a22f35b044.tar.gz'
```

i see eigen.cmake to change URL_HASH but can't find this variable.
please help me what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I also coul't find URL_HASH, so I had to do a (dirty) quick fix:

Lets say you would like to apply the fix for e.g. the **libpng** libraray you have to got to

```
\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-stamp
```

and edit the file download-png.cmake.

In this file change the **${hash_is_good}** parameter from FALSE to TRUE. (Line 18 and Line 30)
Like I said this is really only a very dirty and lazy quickfix, but maybe it helps you.